# Integrate GnuPG with Outlook

Tags: email, security, microsoft-outlook, encryption, gnupg

I want to integrate GnuPG with Outlook in such a way that when it receives an email, it must automatically decrypt the mail using my private key and display on-screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install [GPG4Win](http://www.gpg4win.org). It has a plugin for Microsoft Outlook. Have a look at [this article](http://www.nullamatix.com/how-to-gnupg-gpg4win-for-ms-office-outlook-exchange-and-others/), if you need more info.

Comment: for outlook 2010 you can use version 19 of [outlook-privacy-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/outlook-privacy-plugin/). (version 22-24 do not seem to work correctly)

Comment: Outlook-privacy-plugin works for Outlook 2013 now as well!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at OutlookGnuPG.

http://wiki.github.com/twalrant/OutlookGnuPG/